# How do I create an ER diagram of a database having around 100 tables?

Tags: database-design, mysql-workbench

I have a database with around 100 tables .I used MySQL workbench to ER diagram of the database however the output kinda sucked as the number of tables is many.I would like to generate an image of organised ER. Are there any other tools available?

P.S. I am working in linux.

Comment: Without seeing your database it's hard to be specific.  In general, I'd guess that not all 100 tables have a relationship.  Generate a separate ER for the groups of tables that have a relationship.  We don't recommend specific tools here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the database in modules. A way would be to generate separate diagrams for tables that have a relationship between them, if not all the tables have relationsips. If all tables are interconnected, you still cand group them into modules and make a higher level diagram with those modules instead of entities. Either way, you should split somehow the large diagram, because it is very hard to read and understand such a large structure.